# C# -- PInvokeStackImbalance detected on a well documented function?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Here is my code for a ClickMouse() function:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);


    private const long MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    private const long MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
    private const long MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
    private const long MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;
    private void ClickMouse()
    {
        long X = Cursor.Position.X;
        long Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);

    }
```

For some reason, when my program comes to this code, it throws this error message:

> PInvokeStackImbalance was detected Message: A call to PInvoke function
>   'WindowsFormsApplication1!WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1::mouse_event'
>   has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that
>   the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match
>   the target unmanaged signature.

Please help?

Comment: Stay away from VB6 declarations, they are not right for .NET code.

Answer (score 13):

Looks like your DllImport declaration is wrong. In particular the use of  Int64 (longs), instead of UInt32.

Here's some detail from the PInvoke reference:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.mouse_event

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, 
                               uint dwData,UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
```

Comment: @Sctott I am juggling with a VB to C#.Net upgraded a third party .dll. Based on its document, all parameters are VB6 long type in the original VB programme. .Net upgrader has converted them to `int`. The obvious issue was, there's a password that should be 8 digits and that's beyond int32 type capacity. So we changed it to long in C#. But the problem is, I am getting the same above error when using a particular function that is trying to access/modify a memory. Should we still use `uint`?

Comment: A note from the documentation: "The pInvokeStackImbalance MDA is implemented only for 32-bit x86 platforms."

Answer (score 3):

I found this declaration

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, 
    uint dx, 
    uint dy, 
    uint dwData, 
    IntPtr dwExtraInfo);
```

Answer (score 3):

I was using RealGetWindowClass using the following format.

```
[DllImport("User32", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int RealGetWindowClass(IntPtr hwnd, StringBuilder pszType, int cchType);
```

and i was geting the 'PInvokeStackImbalance' exception/error. But when i changed the CallingConvention to

```
[DllImport("User32", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
```

the error went away. I am using VS2010 on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Win32 API functions are never `Cdecl`; always use `StdCall`, which is the default.

Comment: I used CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl. the error went away :). thanks

Answer (score 2):

To fix PInvokeStackImbalance error:

Press: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

Under "Managed Debugging Assistants" uncheck PInvokeStackImbalance

Answer (score 1):

I changed "Cdecl" to "StdCall" but it didn't work.

As Scott Weinstein mentioned we should use int type.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

[Flags]
public enum MouseEventFlags
{
    LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002,
    LEFTUP = 0x00000004,
    MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020,
    MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040,
    MOVE = 0x00000001,
    ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000,
    RIGHTDOWN = 0x00000008,
    RIGHTUP = 0x00000010
}

public static void LeftClick(int x, int y)
{
    Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
    mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```